# how sys.getsizeof() giving different result

Tags: python

```
import sys
print(sys.getsizeof(4))
print(sys.getsizeof(int))
print(sys.getsizeof(int()))
```

When i try to run the above code it displays the following output

```
28
400
24
```

But since all the given thing inside the parenthesis are int, so how it is giving different output. Can someone explain??

Comment: The second one is _not_ an int. It's the _class_ `int`.

Comment: They are not the same: one is an integer, one is the *type* of integer, one is a function returning an integer.

Answer (score 2):

The first two are different as evident from doing:

```
>>> type(4)
<class 'int'>
>>> type(int)
<class 'type'>
```

The 3d differs from the first due to optimizing the integer space - the more bits you need, the more space Python will require in jumps of 4 - 0 is minimal, and you go up from there:

```
>>> getsizeof(0)
24
>>> getsizeof(32984732)
28
>>> getsizeof(3298473232432432432)
36
```

actually even `1` requires more space than `0` since that's the next size step.